# How to return data from a Step Function Lambda chain linked to a REST API using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, serverless, aws-step-functions

I'm working on a serverless application using AWS CDK that involves a Step Functions state machine integrated with a REST API using AWS API Gateway. The state machine consists of two Lambda functions (`exampleFn` and `exampleFn2`) connected in a chain. I'm encountering an issue where I'm able to pass data from the first function to the second within the Step Function, but I'm struggling to correctly return the data from `exampleFn2` as the API response.

Here's a simplified version of my CDK code:

```js
const exampleFn = new NodejsFunction(this, "exampleFn", {});
const exampleFn2 = new NodejsFunction(this, "exampleFn2", {});

const machineDefinition = new LambdaInvoke(this, "exampleFnInvokeTask", {
  lambdaFunction: exampleFn
}).next(
  new LambdaInvoke(this, "exampleFnInvokeTask2", {
    lambdaFunction: exampleFn2,
    inputPath: "$.Payload"
  })
);

const stateMachine = new sfn.StateMachine(this, "StateMachine", {
  stateMachineName: "stateMachine",
  stateMachineType: sfn.StateMachineType.EXPRESS,
  definitionBody: sfn.DefinitionBody.fromChainable(machineDefinition)
});

const stepFunctionIntegration = StepFunctionsIntegration.startExecution(
  stateMachine,
  {
    integrationResponses: [
      {
        statusCode: "200",
        responseTemplates: {
          "application/json": "$input.json('$')"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
);

const callbackEnd = api.root.addResource("callback");
const _ = callbackEnd.addMethod("POST", stepFunctionIntegration);
```

In the second Lambda function (`exampleFn2`), I aim to structure the response similar to this:

```js
export function handler(event: any) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ event })
  };
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that while the Step Function execution works and passes data between functions correctly, the response I receive from the REST API doesn't contain the data returned by `exampleFn2` as expected. Instead, it seems to return the input to the Step Function.

Is there a specific configuration or modification needed within the CDK setup or integration definitions to ensure that the response from `exampleFn2` is correctly structured and returned by the API Gateway upon completion of the Step Function execution?

Any insights or examples on how to properly set up the integration or handle Step Function output for API Gateway responses would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [Express Workflows](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/) to call your State Machine synchronously and return the result.